# How to check if GADInterstitial() was clicked in Swift

Tags: swift, interstitial

I've seen this question implemented on some apps but I didnt find out how to do that.
The idea is, when the player plays the video, it get rewarded.
I was thinking in doing that with the Google Ads Interstitial. Once the Interstitial is shown how to check if it was clicked or played?